# Method Parameter Without A Parameter Type In C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I try to use  trial version of third party software written C#.
While I try to use its API, I face up with a strange problem.

I am using visual studio 2015 and I found an interesting extended method signature in their API-SDK

```
  public static class CallExtendedInfoEx
  {
        public static void AddToSIPMessage(this CallExtendedInfo info,  msg);
  }
```

**The second parameter type is not exist**.Never seen before in C#. I try to give a generic Object parameter as second parameter, and C# Compiler  gives a strange error

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line
>
> Error CS1503  Argument 2: cannot convert from 'object' to '.'

It works with "null"...No compiler error or run time error [ ignored i think ]

How those guys can able to write such a code in C#? Is It Posssible? Any idea?

> Note : I suspect from a code obscurification problem...But still i do not understand what is going here

```
  IL_0073:  call       void [CallExtendedInfoEx::AddToSIPMessage(class [VoIP.CallExtendedInfo,
                                                                                  class [VoIPSDK]''.'')
```

Comment: what is the type of  `msg`?

Comment: It does not tell.That is the problem.I can not able to figure of it.It does not exist in method signature.

Comment: Compiler says its type is  "." which is meaningless

Comment: Where are you seeing it?  In the decompiled source?  In the documentation?  A parameter _must_ have a type, so it is not valid C#.

Comment: In the decompiled code.

Comment: The _compiled_ code has to be valid.  I'm guessing there's either some bug in the decompiler or they have found a neat obfuscation trick.

Comment: probably a neat obfuscation trick...But that is an ineresting trick

Comment: When you decompile the library with ILDASM, what is the signature of the method?

Comment: It doesn't even have to be obfuscation - there's no telling if the original code even was C#. It might very well be some obscure convention of an obscure CLR language (maybe some attempt at genericity? Discriminated unions?).

Comment: Yo may be right...This a telephony api, so it may be written in C++, wrapped as C#

Comment: ILDASM, Method signature is above...It is strange...Still says  type "."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, looking at the ILDASM output, it's rather obvious that the argument has a perfectly valid type. Sure, it's a type that you can't actually name in C#, but it's perfectly valid in CLR at large.

The fact that you can pass `null` shouldn't be surprising - the argument is a reference type (or convertible from `null`), so `null` is a perfectly valid value. On the other hand, expecting passing an `object` instance is entirely wrong - you can only pass more derived types as argument, not *less*. It's fine to pass `string` (more specific) instead of `object` (less specific), but not the other way around.

Most likely, this is either a method you shouldn't touch (i.e. not part of the public contract of the API/SDK), or you're expected to get instances of the argument from some other method - never using the explicit type anywhere.

Comment: The method is at public part.It seems that parameter type is type that we can't actually have in C#...Maybe a C++ TYPE...But still interesting....THANKS

Comment: @HippiasMinor You can have it - you just can't ever explicitly name it. That still allows you to pass it from a return value of another method, or store it in a local using `var`, for example. You could even store it in a field as `dynamic`, though that breaks the static typing. What does the documentation say about the usage?

Comment: Nothing...Documentation is bad

Comment: My real interest is not using SDK... I just wonder how this happen...Just curious...THANKS

Comment: @HippiasMinor Well, that means it's *not* part of the API contract. The fact that it's `public` doesn't mean it's part of the API :). As far as I can tell, you should use custom message manipulators to modify messages, not this method. They might have even explicitly wanted to avoid people messing around with dangerous things, or it's simply part of the obfuscation.

Comment: But their API for    Message Manipulating is more bad : ISIPMessageManipulator...which is also dangerous .. It allow you manipulate all messages not just u wanted ...If you have business logic which consume time, then you just block message passing...

Comment: @HippiasMinor Well, I didn't say the API was great. I've seen a few telephony APIs, and so far, I haven't found *any* that were reasonable. Might have to do with the way the whole telephony systems are designed (and pass along their design flaws and legacy architectures), or maybe they just don't care :))

Comment: Without actually testing this theory, I wonder if it's a private type within the dll you're referencing and that's why you are unable to see the type in the decompile.

Comment: @Physics-Compute Private types cannot be exposed by public members. And in any case, the name would still be correct.

Answer (score 3):

This is not valid C# code. Some decompiler probably gave you that code, or the documentation where you copied this out of is faulty.

Comment: If it is not valid C# , then how can I use method with null ? Compiler does not give any warning.

Comment: What do you mean by "use with null"? Do you want to call the method?

Comment: I just play with method.Could not find real type.So i just pass null to method.It compiles.Of course it is useless.But just to check

Comment: Is your question answered then?

Comment: No...If it was not a valid C# Code, compiler should give error...It does not...When I pass just null...But when i just pass generic object , it says wrong type since type is "." which i never seen befor

Comment: Are you referencing a compiled library (DLL) or compiling their source code.  If the library is already compiled then you wouldn't get a compiler error from _their_ code.

Comment: @HippiasMinor `null` is not of type `object` - it's of an inferred type, in this case the `.` that's giving you trouble. The only thing this experiment tells you is that the argument is a reference type, or convertible from null. The C# compiler statically knows the type just fine. The problem is with your decompiler (or, to be more exact, you expecting to use an undocumented part of the SDK). If you don't understand this, you need to read up on argument type variance - it's fine to pass `string` instead of `object`, but *not* the other way around.

Comment: Compiler does not know type...It says "."...So what is "." type Luaan?You should read the question before giving advice about argument type variance

Comment: @HippiasMinor It's a perfectly valid type - apparently, with a few non-ASCII characters, but a perfectly valid type anyway. The fact that it can't be declared in C# specifically is irrelevant - there's no rule that says you can only ever use identifiers that make sense in all the CLR languages (e.g. VB would not distinguish between types `myType` and `MyType`, while C# has no problem with that). I expect that you could define a type like you have in a language like F#, which allows you to escape identifiers like this using backticks (so a type name like `Do some stuff` is perfectly valid).